# spring schedular for ervery day 3'0 clock

Tags: spring

I want to schedule some tasks which needs to be run at everyday 3'o clock.

Spring version : 3.0

Any help how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using Cron expression in schedular annotations

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * ?")
public void performTask() {

    //Do Something Here

}
```

And add below line in application conext xml file

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Cron Expression Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm